# Одна форма, но разные значения для неё, производительность

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-native

Ребят, помогите решить проблему, в react относительно недавно. Проблема в том, что в приложении на RN имеется компонента - `<TaskInput />`. Внутрь компоненты пролетают props со всякими title и прочей простой мишурой. Эта компонента вставляется на одном скрине в 2 местах, но по смыслу она разная, в одной будет вводиться главное название, в другой описание. Нужно разделить состояние, то есть презентационная компонента одна, а строчки состояния в `state` - разные, но тут проблема, ведь контейнер один будет у компоненты, в него я буду передавать в mapStateToProps разные две строчки, получается, если одна из них обновилась, то будет происходить rerender презентационной компоненты. Но, компоненты то две на скрине, я буду вводить текст в одну, в другой он не изменится - не спорю, но перерисовываться они будут обе, а это совсем не хорошо. Есть вариант поработать с хуками и локальным state у TaskInput, но я слышал что это хуже по производительности)) В общем, помогите найти мне золотую середину)

Comment: Если вы используете хуки, посмотрите в сторону useMemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитал документацию в разделе "Поднятие состояния" и "Управляемые компоненты". Сделал с хранением значения в redux, дал уникальное имя каждому инпуту и по нему определяю значение какого инпута следует контролить в данный момент.